# custom control string property C#

Tags: c#

So I am making a custom control for my program. I went to add a string property but when I tried to change it C# crashes. This is the code I am using

```
private string series = "None";
[Description("Tells What the Series is")]
[Category("Element")]
[DefaultValue("None")]
public string Series
{
    get { return series; }
    set { Series = value; }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: The problem is the set { Series = value;} should have been series = value with small s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are recursively setting it.

```
private string series = "None";
[Description("Tells What the Series is")]
[Category("Element")]
[DefaultValue("None")]
public string Series
{
   get { return series; }
   set { series = value; }  // notice series not Series
}
```

Might I suggest using automatic properties?

```
[Description("Tells What the Series is")]
[Category("Element")]
[DefaultValue("None")]
public string Series
{
    get; set;
}
```

You will have to initialize the value in your constructor.

Comment: If you cannot use automatic properties (for example, if you need to handle INotifyPropertyChanged), then it may help to at least use a standardized naming nomenclature for your fields to make your intent more obvious.  Two of the more "popular" are to insert an underscore or "m" to the beginning of your variable name: _series or mSeries, or even m_Series.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set the property  `Series` recursively in the setter of the property. This will result in a `StackOverflowException`.

```
set { series = value; }
```

Is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Yoy got an endless loop in your app, so it crashes with a stackoverflow error I guess.

```
   set { Series = value; }
```

should be

```
   set { series = value; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you're trying to set the proprty value itself in the "set", thus creating an infinite recursion.

change

```
set { Series = value; }
```

to

```
set { series = value; }
```

(lowercase s).